# Различные LayoutManager для разных View в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, layoutmanager

Имеется RecyclerView с элементами типа CardView. Необходимо реализовать второй View для рекламных полей - с этим в классе адаптера вроде разобрался. Проблема в следующем: в самой активности, где я использую RecyclerView, layoutManager задаю такой - `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2))` (т.е таблицей в 2 столбца), но рекламный View должен располагаться на всю ширину экрана, т.е установка на него должна быть такой: `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 1))` (соответственно, та же таблица, но на 1 столбец). В общем, сам вопрос - как для нового View задать другой LayoutManager, или, возможно, как изменить LayoutManager для конкретного элемента, а затем, для последующих, вернуть прежний? Заранее благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Вроде бы вот тут ответ есть: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41120981/3212712

Comment: Использовал информацию по ссылке - теперь все представления выводятся в 1 столбец (т.е. как при GridLayoutManager(this, 1)), как пофиксить - понять не могу

Comment: Покажите ваш код - возможно вы где-то что-то не так написали. Надо бы показать адаптер и где вы использовали решение из ссылки в первом комменте.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется вы не правильно понимаете что такое LayoutManager. Он не задается для каждой конкретной View.

LayoutManager - это сущность которая отвечает за расположение и измерение View внутри RecyclerView. Т.е. в нем описана общая логика отображения.

Есть несколько готовых решений:

- [LinearLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/LinearLayoutManager)
- [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/GridLayoutManager)
- [SpannableLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager)

Вот еще пару решений по теме:

- [FlexBoxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)
- [WearableLinearLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/wear/widget/WearableLinearLayoutManager)

Если ни один из них не подходит вам, то вам нужно писать свой кастомный LayoutManager. В котором вы и будете описывать логику нужную вам.